# Can't see volume adjustments made with Bluetooth headphones

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I am using [Beoplay E6 headphones](https://www.bang-olufsen.com/en/earphones/beoplay-e6?variant=beoplay-e6-black) that connect via Bluetooth. When paired with my Macbook Pro I can adjust the volume but I cannot see the pop-up volume bar that appears when you normally use keyboard volume controls.

I cannot see this icon:

[image]

Any idea why this is and how could I fix it?

Comment: Why do you want it to appear?

Comment: So I can see what the volume is